# What does this piece of C++ code do?

Tags: c++, pointers, winsock

I am reading a WinSock tutorial, and I notice the following line of code:

```
bind(listener, (SOCKADDR*)(&clientinfo), sizeof(clientinfo))
```

listener is a `SOCKET` object, clientinfo is a `SOCKADDR_IN` object.

I know `&` is the "address-of" operator, and `*` is the deference operator. I notice it looks similar to casting in C#.

What does: `(SOCKADDR*)(&clientinfo)` mean in the context of that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(&clientinfo)` takes address of `clientinfo` and `(SOCKADDR*)` [typecasts](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) this to pointer to `SOCKADDR`

In `C++`, I would prefer to use `static_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&clientinfo)`

You can read more about [static_cast here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Answer (score 1):

It's a cast. It casts a pointer to a SOCKADDR_IN into a pointer to a SOCKADDR. These two types happen to be compatible.

It's basically how polymorphism is done in C, and `bind` is a C API.